L298N and Raspberry Pi 4, trying to do 2 DC motor controls; RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi
What do I need to do to correct this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/taso/project/motorsurucu.py", > line 14, in 
GPIO.setup(en_1, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!

Code:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# GPIO Pinlerinin Tanımlanması
en_1 = 13
in_1 = 27
in_2 = 22
in_3 = 25
in_4 = 8
en_2 = 12

# GPIO Pinlerinin Yapılandırılması
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(en_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in_2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in_3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(in_4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(en_2, GPIO.OUT)

def ileri():  
    print("İleri gidiyor")
    GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(8, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)

def dur():
    print("durdu")
    GPIO.output([en_1, en_2], GPIO.LOW) # Motorlara enerji verilmesini kesiyoruz

try:
    while True:
      

        ileri()
        time.sleep(1)
        dur()
        time.sleep(1)

     
except KeyboardInterrupt:  # Ctrl+C ile çıkmak için
    GPIO.cleanup()



Are you running the script with the user "pi"? Are you sure that the user belongs to the "gpio" group?

i'm using it for the first time and I don't know much about raspberry. i will investigate and check
